# locations of maximum values of tensorflow tensor across an axis

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a rank 3 tensor and another empty tensor of same shape. I am trying to find the maximum values across 3rd(Z) axis for all X,Y locations and insert `1` into the corresponding location in the empty tensor. I have achieved this in numpy in the following way

```py
a = np.random.rand(5,5,3)>=0.5
empty_tensor = np.zeros((5,5,3))
max_z_indices = a.argmax(axis=-1)
empty_tensor[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None],np.arange(a.shape[1]),max_z_indices] = 1
```

In tensorflow I have

```py
a_tf = tf.Variable(a)
empty_tensor_tf = tf.Variable(np.zeros((5,5,3)))
max_z_indices = sess.run(tf.argmax(a_tf,axis=-1))
```

I know that I can explicitly write the X,Y,Z indices of max values along 3rd dimension of tensor `a_tf` and use `tf.scatter_nd_update` to update `empty_tensor_tf` but I was hoping to find a better way (broadcasting) as in the last line of numpy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.reduce_max` to get the max value for each z-index, then use `tf.where` to convert it to 1 or 0 according to the `cond`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# tf_a is (5,5,3) tensor
max_val = tf.reduce_max(tf_a, axis=-1,keepdims=True)
cond = tf.equal(tf_a, max_val)
res = tf.where(cond, tf.ones_like(tf_a), tf.zeros_like(tf_a))
```