# TensorFlow: How to find location of single instance of maximum value of a tensor across an axis

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have a rank 3 tensor which is of size `[batch, height, width]` and I am trying to find the coordinates of the maximum value for each batch element. Essentially I need to find the pixel coordinates of the maximum valued pixel for every image in a batch.

Below is a sample of my current approach which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58332517/20488397).

assume that `100` is the maximum value and will occur at least once per batch element.

```
x = tf.constant([[[1, 2, 3], 
                 [4, 100, 5],
                 [6, 100, 8]],
                 
                 [[3, 100, 1], 
                 [5, 6, 7],
                 [9, 8, 7]],
                 
                 [[1, 3, 7], 
                 [2, 4, 7],
                 [100, 5, 7]],
                 
                 [[1, 3, 7], 
                 [2, 4, 7],
                 [4, 5, 100]]])


max_val = 100
cond = tf.equal(x, max_val)
res = tf.where(cond)

#res =
#tf.Tensor(
#[[0 1 1]   
# [0 2 1]   <== second maximum axis 0
# [1 0 1]
# [2 2 0]
# [3 2 2]], shape=(5, 3), dtype=int64)
```

This approach works for the most part but allows for duplicate maximums. The problem is I need to find *exactly one* maximum per batch element, it doesn't matter which maximum valued element it is.

One idea I had was to throw out rows of `res` with duplicate values in the 0th column, but I'm not sure how to do that or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below in place of this : `res = tf.where(cond)` to find the coordinates of the maximum value for each batch element:

```
res = tf.where(cond, tf.ones_like(x), tf.zeros_like(x))
res
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1]]], dtype=int32)>
```